# Showing $f $ is not injective.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I know that $f:\Bbb{R}\setminus  \{-1, 1\} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}, f(x)=\frac1{x^2-1}$ is not an injection. But I cannot arrive at this result through the proof method where one sets $ f(x_{1})=f(x_{2})$ and then gets to $x_{2}^2=x_{1}^2$ which would imply that $x_{1}=x_{2}$ ($x_{1}, x_{2}\in\Bbb{R}\setminus  \{-1, 1\}$).  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

$x_2^{2}=x_1^{2}$ does not imply $x_2=x_1$. It implies $x_2=x_1$ or $x_2=-x_1$. $f$ is not an injection because $f(-2)=f(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can fill in and arrive at the fact that: $f(-2)=f(2)$. You therefore have to numbers which have the same image, which proves that the function $f$ is not a injection.